# passing a parameter from javascript to php

Tags: php, javascript

Hello everybody I'm trying to pass a parameter to my controller.php from javascript, but it doesn't pass and gives me error of undefined URL. kindly help me i shall be thankful to you...Here is my code

```
function JSfunction(assetid)
{
    window.location="controller.php?command=delete&assetid=".assetid;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're mixing PHP and JS, you use + to concatenate strings in JavaScript

Change the code to this and it should work:

```
function JSfunction(assetid) {
    window.location="controller.php?command=delete&assetid=" + assetid;
}
```

What you are doing now is creating a string and accessing the `assetid` attribute of that string which is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

you should set `window.location` to the full URL, not just the relative URL. I.E.

```
window.location="http://foo.com/controller.php?command=delete&assetid=" + assetid;
```

BTW, JS uses `+` to concat, not `.`

Answer (score 1):

1. You must include server address, if it is being used locally,it can be denoted by http://localhost/AppName/pages?QueryString.
2. Concate string with plus sign, dot is used in php script for concatenation.

Comment: Actually, most browsers support relative URLs when dealing with `window.location`